# How to add line breaks to quine function,I want proper indentation and line breaks after each line of source code

Tags: javascript

Here I am using a function to show the source code of another function but the source code is not properly indented and no line breaks are there.If I print the same code in console it is properly indented.
I just want to make the source code to be properly indented with whitespaces and line breaks. I don't know how to achieve this.Although I have tried a pattern matching but no luck. Thanks in advance

```js
function calc(){
    var x,y,x;
     x = 10;
     y = 56;
     z = x + y;
     console.log('The sum is: ' + z);
  }
function showCode(){
  var target = document.getElementById("writeCode");
  var sourceCode;
  sourceCode = String(calc);
  target.innerHTML = sourceCode; //Not indented and no white spaces
  console.log(String(calc)); //Everything is fine
}
```

```html
<button onclick = "showCode()">SHOW SOURCE</button>  
<p id = "writeCode"></p>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try `<pre id = "writeCode"></pre>`, it is the tag that is probably the most correct in that case.

> The  tag defines preformatted text.
>
> Text in a  element is displayed in a fixed-width font (usually Courier), and it preserves both spaces and line breaks.

[Read more at w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_pre.asp)

Answer (score 1):

Just use `pre` tag to get as it is rendering in html

```js
function calc(){
    var x,y,x;
     x = 10;
     y = 56;
     z = x + y;
     console.log('The sum is: ' + z);
  }
function showCode(){
  var target = document.getElementById("writeCode");
  var sourceCode;
  sourceCode = String(calc);
  target.innerHTML = sourceCode;
}
```

```html
<button onclick = "showCode()">SHOW SOURCE</button>  
<pre id = "writeCode"></pre>
```